# Multiple integral related to the volume of a convex body

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, multiple-integral, convex-geometry

I was trying to figure the volume of a convex body and I ran into the following integral:

$$\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left( \int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1 |x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta)|\,dxdy \right)^{-2}d\theta.$$

So you have a geometric idea we are integrating on the first quadrant of the 2-dimensional sphere and on centered square of side 2. As it's the volume of a convex body I know it must be finite but I'm incapable to solve it. I will appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Math_QED: probably the fact that the innermost integral over $[-1,1]^2$ is not that trivial.

Comment: What stops me is that I don't know how to get ride of the absolute value since what is inside of it it's positive or negative depending on the $\theta$. You can picture that as a line crossing the square through the origin and the positive and negative parts are determined by the intersection of such line with the square.

Answer (score 3):

Tricky question. If we exploit
$$ |K|=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(K s)}{\pi s^2}\,ds \tag{1} $$
we get that
$$ \iint_{[-1,1]^2}\left|ax+by\right|\,dx\,dy = \frac{4}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{a b s^2-\sin(a s)\sin(b s)}{a b s^4}\,ds \tag{2}$$
so by computing the RHS of $(2)$ through Fourier or Laplace transforms:
$$ \iint_{[-1,1]^2}\left|ax+by\right|\,dx\,dy = \frac{2}{3\max(a,b)}\left[a^2+b^2+2\max(a,b)^2\right]\tag{3} $$
for any $a,b\geq 0$. By setting $a=\cos\theta$ and $b=\sin\theta$, for any $\theta\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ we have
$$ \iint_{[-1,1]^2}\left|x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta\right|\,dx\,dy = \frac{2}{3\max(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)}\left[1+2\max(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)^2\right]\tag{4}$$
and the original integral equals

$$ I=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\left[\frac{3\cos\theta}{2(1+2\cos^2\theta)}\right]^2\,d\theta+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\left[\frac{3\sin\theta}{2(1+2\sin^2\theta)}\right]^2\,d\theta \tag{5}$$
and by symmetry and the substitution $\theta=\arctan u $ it follows that:
$$\boxed{ I = \color{red}{\frac{1}{48}\left(9+2\pi\sqrt{3}\right)}}\tag{6} $$

Comment: This is a great answer but I'll need to put some deep thought into it to understand what it's going on. I'll be back as soon as I get it!

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to understand the second equality (after: we get that) and the third one (where we are supposed to use the Fourier transform) but I don't understand any of them. Could you give me any references or hints?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\bracks{\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}
\verts{\vphantom{\large A}x\cos\pars{\theta} + y\sin\pars{\theta}}
\,\dd x\,\dd y}^{-2}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sec^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta \over
\ds{\bracks{\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}
\verts{x + y\tan\pars{\theta}}\,\dd x\,\dd y}^{2}}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{t\ =\ \tan\pars{\theta}}{=}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over
\ds{\bracks{\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\verts{x + ty}\,\dd x\,\dd y}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over
\ds{\bracks{\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\verts{x + ty}\,\dd x\,\dd y}^{2}}}
\,,\quad
\pars{\substack{\ds{by\ splitting\ over\ \pars{0,1}\ and\ \pars{1,\infty}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{Set\ t\ \mapsto\ {1 \over t}\ in\ the\ integral\ over\ \pars{1,\infty}}}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> Hereafter, I'll evaluate the "$\ds{xy}$*-integral*":

\begin{align}
\left.\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\verts{x + ty}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,
\right\vert_{\ 0\ <\ t\ <\ 1} & =
\overbrace{2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x + ty}\,\dd x\,\dd y}
^{\ds{=\ 1 + t}}\ +\
2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\verts{x - ty}\,\dd x\,\dd y 
\end{align}
The second integral is evaluated as follows:
\begin{align}
&\left.2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\verts{x - ty}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,
\right\vert_{\ 0\ <\ t\ <\ 1} =
2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-ty}^{1 - ty}\verts{x}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
2\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{%
\int_{-ty}^{0}\pars{-x}\,\dd x\,\dd y +
\int_{0}^{1 - ty}x\,\dd x\,\dd y} =
2\int_{0}^{1}\pars{t^{2}y^{2} - ty + {1 \over 2}}\,\dd y =
{2 \over 3}\,t^{2} - t + 1
\\[5mm] &\
\mbox{such that}\quad
\bbx{\left.\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\verts{x + ty}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,
\right\vert_{\ 0\ <\ t\ <\ 1} =
{2 \over 3}\pars{t^{2} + 3}}
\end{align}

> \eqref{1} becomes:

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\bracks{\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}
\verts{\vphantom{\large A}x\cos\pars{\theta} + y\sin\pars{\theta}}
\,\dd x\,\dd y}^{-2}\,\dd\theta =
{9 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over \pars{t^{2} + 3}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{\root{3} \over 24}\,\pi + {3 \over 16}} \approx 0.4142
\end{align}

Comment: Great answer! Thank you for posting it.